# Open multiple files in Windows 11

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Windows 11 is here, everything is new and shiny, but productivity goes down the drain... at least I thought at first. Its bad, but after all not as bad as I feared. But le me explain.

I wanted to open 16 Excel-files from Windows Explorer, they contain data that need to be merged into one file. So instead of "open one file, process the content, close it, open the next file", I'd like to open all at once, and close the file after I have processed it. I go to the folder, Ctrl-a, Enter, nothing happens. I try again, log out, restart my computer, search se interwebs, it seems it should be working, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

After a (way tooooo long) moment I find it only works for maximum of *15* to open simultaneously, not *16*.

So yes you can, there are several approaches:

- Select multiple but less than 16 files:

  - with the mouse by clicking on the white space left or right of the files and drag
  - hold Ctrl and click to select individual files
  - select one file, then hold shift while using up/down keys
- hit Enter

Comment: Rather than complain on here about Microsoft's implementation, you'd be better posting on https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback or on the User Voice site.